# How can I execute few tests every time after Test method which is using Data Provider

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

```
   @Test(dataProvider="LInData",dataProviderClass=LInDataProvider.class)
public void testLIn(String fname) throws InterruptedException// return 3 fname and this test executed 10 times
{
    System.out.println("test start");

    System.out.println("fname:"+fname);     

        System.out.println("test completed");
}

@Test(dataProvider="LInData",dataProviderClass=LInDataProvider.class)
public void me(String fname,String lname,String em,String pass) 
{
   System.out.println("Other tests");
}
```

It produces this result:

fname:andy

fname:jack

fname:palm

other tests

**But I need below one, Please tell me how can I get below o/p:**

fname:andy

other tests

fname:jack

other tests

fname:palm

other tests

Answer (score 1):

It's the perfect case for [factories](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories)!

```
public class MyTest {

   private final String fname
   private final String lname;
   private final String em;
   private final String pass;

   @Factory(dataProvider="LInData",dataProviderClass=LInDataProvider.class)
   public MyTest(String fname, String lname, String em, String pass) {
      // init attributes
   }     

   @Test
   public void testLIn() throws InterruptedException // return 3 fname and this test executed 10 times
    {
        System.out.println("test start");        
        System.out.println("fname:" + fname);
        System.out.println("test completed");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"testLIn"})
    public void me() {
       System.out.println("Other tests");
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this logic but I does not get expected o/p. First test runs for number of times data supplied and then other test. For Example: If dataProvider is having 3 set of data, then  testLIn() runs thrice and then me() once. But I want me()  to be executed with data set. like one time testLIn()  and thenme()

Comment: Got the solution: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1oPK9QjUy_FSGtVemllLVplRzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should use your solution as answer of the question and accept it. It will close the question.